# Selecting multiple options more than once in a select field

Tags: html, css

I have the following `select field` where a given service can be selected:

```
<select class="form-control" data-role="select2" id="services" multiple name="services">
    <option value="1">Service 1</option>
    <option value="2">Service 2</option>
    <option value="3">Service 3</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to be able to **select the same option multiple times**?

i.e. in the select field I would choose `Service 1` `Service 1` `Service 3`, so `Service 1` twice and `Service 3` once.

Currently once I select `Service 1`, this option is no longer available from the choice of options in the `select` field to choose again.

Thanks for any help here! :-)

Comment: Good question, but that's not possible. Maybe it's possible if you use two controls and append it on them. Also, if you have everything given twice or thrice, then it's possible.

Comment: If the list of Services isn’t too long, consider simply placing `<input type="number" step="1" min="0" />` after each Service. You’ll have to use a table or some other layout option. `<select>`s cannot do this.

Comment: you need to look into writing custom select